# How do I Increment Integer and save it for use when program is re-run?

Tags: iphone, ios, int, increment, nsnumber

I am trying to increment a number in a simple way that won't cause duplicates or missed numbers. This number will eventually be stored in a field in my coreData entity as an order number which is why I can't have duplicates or missed numbers.

I have a view for entering orders and when it initialises it must provide the correct order number, this is what I have coded:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
 // If no orders have previously been entered the order number will be changed from 0 to 1
          if (orderNumber == 0) {
          orderNumber = orderNumber + 1;
          }
// If orders have previously been entered the order number will be given the value that has previously been stored in orderNumber
          else orderNumber = orderNumber;


NSLog(@"The Order Number is %d",orderNumber); 
}
```

When the form on the view has been completed a done button is pressed, this finalises the order. All textfields on the view are cleared and the order number is increased by 1 so that the next order can be entered.

```
-(void) doneButtonTapped:(id)sender{
   orderNumber = orderNumber + 1;
   NSLog(@"orderNumber is increased to %d",orderNumber);
}
```

My header file includes the following:

```
int orderNumber;
@property (nonatomic,assign) int orderNumber;
```

This works while the application is running but if I quit the application and re-run it my orderNumber starts back at 1.

How can I store/save the value associated to orderNumber for use in viewDidLoad when the application runs again?

Is my method for incrementing ok or is there a better way? I have used int but I see others use NSNumber, I am not sure if there are advantages & disadvantages of using one or the other.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to store `int`s and other basic types (`BOOL`, `float`, `NSString`, `NSArray`).

For example, you can retrieve the `int` using

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int orderNumber = [prefs integerForKey:@"orderNumber"];
```

and then save the `int` using

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setInteger:orderNumber  forKey:@"orderNumber"];
```

When necessary, you can also call

```
   [prefs synchronize];
```

to ensure that you are accessing the most up to date information. This is especially useful if you are accessing this `int` in multiple places in your app.

Comment: It's better to use `NSInteger` for the purpose instead of the `int`. On 64 bit arch it causes lose of precision since `NSInteger` is defined as `long`.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{

   NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   //now take an int to store value

   int count = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"my_key"]; 
   // since we didn't stored any value for key "my_key" the above statement returns 0 by default

   //do your stuff by using that variable


  // now to increment and store the updated value ,we have to write following stuff

  [userDefaults setInteger:count+1 forKey:@"my_key"];

  [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `NSUserDefaults` like so:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
 // If no orders have previously been entered the order number will be changed from 0 to 1
    int orderNumber = [[NSUserDefaults sharedDefaults] intForKey:@"orderNumber"];
    if (orderNumber == 0) {
          orderNumber = orderNumber + 1;
          }
// If orders have previously been entered the order number will be given the value that has previously been stored in orderNumber
          else orderNumber = orderNumber;
    [[NSUserDefaults sharedDefaults] setInt:orderNumber ForKey:@"orderNumber"];
    [[NSUserDefaults sharedDefaults] synchronize];

NSLog(@"The Order Number is %d",orderNumber); 
}


-(void) doneButtonTapped:(id)sender{
   orderNumber = orderNumber + 1;
   [[NSUserDefaults sharedDefaults] setInt:orderNumber ForKey:@"orderNumber"];
   [[NSUserDefaults sharedDefaults] synchronize];
   NSLog(@"orderNumber is increased to %d",orderNumber);
}
```

Comment: For some reason it wouldn't work. It came up with class method +sharedDefaults not found. I used the standardUserDefaults instead and that worked. Thanks for your quick and detailed response anyway